# Is this "Permanent magnet gun" real or fake?

Tags: magnetic-fields, home-experiment, perpetual-motion

There are several [videos on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UeIasNv19GE) describing linear accelerator built solely from permanent magnets, put like this:

[image]

I find it hard to believe that this can work because if it did, it would be exploitable to gain energy. Where would that energy come from then?

I think it's faked and that the magnet should find equilibrium in the middle of the contraption. Am I right or wrong?

I'm willing to test it if I don't get conclusive answer, but I thought I'd as first before wasting money on bunch of magnets.

Comment: "would be exploitable to gain energy" at the expense of the magnets losing magnetization, because there is potential energy sthttps://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/67107/from-where-do-the-permanent-magnets-get-energy-fromored  in the macroscopic permanent magnet.

Comment: @annav That's what I meant. Harvesting energy stored in the arrangement of atoms that creates magnetic field - while increasing it's entropy. I wonder what would happen if you tried the same with superconductive magnet with persistent switch.

Comment: correct link  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/67107/from-whe‌​re-do-the-permanent-‌​magnets-get-energy-f‌​rom  stored in the macroscopic permanent magnet.  You cannot win, the energy to make superconducting magnets is much more than you would get out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the video I see that the author needs quite some force to load the gun. So here he puts the projectile in a high potential state, i.e. he provides the energy during the loading process. When released this energy accelerates the projectile. Hence, no violation of energy conservation.

**Edit**
Here a small representation with python and ten dipole magnets:
[image]
*Top: field lines in top view. Bottom: x-Field (arb.u.) on projectile path.*

If you came from the left you have to somewhat overcome the negative bump. You see that the last max is almost as high as the first min is deep. That's why lubricant is important, as metnioned by @xcoderx. Actually, the thing looks better if you make it shorter. On longer ones the max approaches a saturation value and you'll have more friction loss.

*Extra*
Just looked at the video again because the author inserts the magnet  as [NS] and [SN]. The behavior corresponds to the lower graph. In one case one has to overcome the first bump by pushing, but the total distance is not very much as the magnet is later attracted by the second bump. In the second case, the reversed magnet is attracted by the first bump, the author then pushes it over the second bump, which the naturally results in a larger distance.

Comment: So it's kinda like magnetic slingshot?

Comment: Well, that would probably the most simple case: just press two north poles together, then release them. The nice thing here is the field geometry that allows for a "maximum" in the 1D path, so you can load from one side and it is released when you overcome that "max". Note that in 3D there is no maximum but a saddle point, due to properties of harmonic potentials.

Comment: But what if that contraption was longer? Shouln't there be a limit on it's length? Also I assume it wouldn't work in a circle, right?