# If the magnetic force doesn't do work then what does it?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Let's assume I have a conductive rod with mass $m$ and with steady current $I$. I can make the current flow in such a direction and magnitude that the magnetic force will make it move up, thus something is doing work on the rod. But it can't be the magnetic field since it's perpendicular to the direction of motion.

I still don't understand; what is doing work on the rod?

Comment: This question has been asked several times on SE. You should search the site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the mechanism by which magnetic fields do work?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/89398/what-is-the-mechanism-by-which-magnetic-fields-do-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magnetic fields do no work on freely moving electric charges (that is, the Lorentz force $qv\times B$). They can do work on magnetic dipoles, whether from permanent magnets or electrical currents.